# Multiple GROUP BY to count MIN elements?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose in MySQL I have a table `comments`, which has fields `post_id, author_id, date`, and `comment`.

If I want the first comment for each post, I can do

```
SELECT post_id, author_id, comment, MIN(date) AS comment_date 
FROM comments 
GROUP BY post_id;
```

If I want to get the authors who have made the most comments, I can do

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) AS total_comments 
FROM comments 
GROUP BY author_id 
ORDER BY total_comments DESC;
```

I want to combine these, to answer the question "What authors have made the most *first* comments?" How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is broken SQL:

```
SELECT post_id, author_id, comment, MIN(date) AS comment_date 
FROM comments 
GROUP BY post_id;
```

The `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` are inconsistent.  Just because your database happens to allow the syntax doesn't mean that it does what you want.

To answer this question:

> "What authors have made the most first comments?"

The correct form of your first query is:

```
select c.*
from comments c
where c.date = (select min(c2.date)
                from comments c2
                where c2.post_id = c.post_id
               );
```

There are other ways to write this logic as well, notably using window functions.

Then you just want aggregation:

```
select author_id, count(*)
from comments c
where c.date = (select min(c2.date)
                from comments c2
                where c2.post_id = c.post_id
               )
group by author_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note:  This assumes that the minimum date does indeed correspond to "the first comment", even when multiple authors make comments on the same date.